# Linking anchor tag on homepage to a particular tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I have a navigation menu at the top of my webpage with a drop down. For example the service page under nav has a drop down of our other services that go to a service page with a tab structure like so:

```
<section class="tabs">

    <ul class="tab-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#first">First Tab</a></li>
        <li><a href="#second">Second Tab</a></li>
        <li><a href="#third">Third Tab</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <p>Here's the first piece of content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content active">
        <p>My tab is active so I'll show up first! Inb4 tab 3!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <p>Don't forget about me! I'm tab 3!</p>
    </div>

 </section>
```

and I would like like to make it so that I could use my achor tags on my home page to link directly to tab 3 or 1 or 2 of my choosing as well as when I refresh the page with the tabs the tab doens't jump to the active tab. How can I do this with javascript? I attempted it with this hash check function bit of code:

```
$(function () {
    $(".tab-content").hide().first().show();
    $(".tab-nav li:first").addClass("active");

    $(".tab-nav a").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('li').addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
        $($(this).attr('href')).show().siblings('.tab-content').hide();
    });

    var hash = $.trim( window.location.hash );

    if (hash) $('.tab-nav a[href$="'+hash+'"]').trigger('click');

});
```

The problem is, is that when I click the second tab, it shows the content on the first tab... but tab 3 looks fine. But when I click on tab 3 and then go back to tab 2, no content displays under tab 2. Maybe someone can simply my code for what I'm trying to accomplish?

ps. I'm using the gumby framework for my tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `$($(this).attr('href'))` isn't going to find anything, so none of the tabs would be working anyway.

Apart from that, the hash linking code seems to be fine.

---

I've rewritten the code so that it works now below.

**Link:** http://jsfiddle.net/s8Ttm/2/

**Code:**

```
$(".tab-nav a").bind('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('li').addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('active').hide();
    console.log($('.tab-content:eq('+$(this).index()+')'));
    $('.tab-content:eq('+$(this).parents('li').index()+')').addClass('active').show();
});

$('.tab-nav a').first().click();

var hash = $.trim( window.location.hash );
if (hash) $('.tab-nav a[href$="'+hash+'"]').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great when I'm on the home page but when I'm on the services tab page (where the tabs are) the tabs work fine but my navigation drop down menu wont take me to any of the other tabs I click on. ie. drop down menu works on home page and any other page where the tabs aren't but when i'm on the page where the tabs are the drop down wont work.

Comment: @user2241963 could you show me where this is happening? ( i.e where this home/services page is )

Comment: Sure. For simplicity here's my site in a nutshell:  Three pages: a home page, a service page, and a contact page. All three have the same nav bar buttons With HOME, SERVICES, CONTACT with the services button having a drop down menu which links to the tabs on the services page.  On the service page itself there are three tabs. When I'm on the service page itself and I click the drop down menu to navigate to other tabs (rather than just clicking on the tabs themselves) nothing happens. Only when I'm on Home and contact will the navigation menu take me to the tabs on the service page.

Comment: @user2241963 sorry, I meant like a live example, or at leas the html structure of the navigation in a fiddle